# Wordpress widget not appearing in editors widget list

Tags: widgets

I have created a custom Wordpress (5.6) widget named "Server" which can be added to all sidebars without any problem:

[image: Widget list for sidebars]

But when I try to add the widget to a page content with the editor this widget does *not* appear in the list of available widgets. What do I miss?

[image: Widget list in editor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "widgets" in the editor are a type of [Block](https://wordpress.org/support/article/blocks/), not "true" Widgets, like the ones listed in *Appearance > Widgets*. Each of these types of widget are developed completely differently, so there isn't a way to add true widgets as blocks or vice versa, and any added to one section will not automatically appear in the other.

Yes, this is needlessly confusing.